# Import NodeJS file in regular JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 files, an `index.html`, a `Learner.js`, and a `bot.js`. Right now, the `bot.js` is a regular js file that I load in the html file with `<script>` tags, and the `Learner.js` is a NodeJS file. The only reason I have this file is because I want to use a Neural Net library but it only works with NodeJS, not regular javascript, so how exactly would I reference any functions, varibles, etc. in my `bot.js` that exist in `Learner.js`, should I load the file using `<script>` tags, or what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can't call server side (nodejs) functions in your `index.html` unless using something like https://nwjs.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can add it simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Learner.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="bot.js"></script>
```

But, if your `Learner.js` javascript file use some native `node.js` engine functions or simply `require()` calls, it wont work.

In this case, consider to try to use [`Browserify`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) or similar tools, to allow run nodejs specific stuff into the browser.

All these tools have limitations, not all code can be executed browser side.

When it is not possible you have to implement a web service server in nodejs (for example using a REST api, JSON over RPC pattern, ...) to allow execute the code and get the result in the browser.

Comment: Of course. Just add some shim for some common modules. Not all nodejs can be executed in the browser (i/o, network, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that its (potentially) complicated.

There are things that node.js can do that browser JavaScript *cannot* do (like have filesystem access), and things that the browser *doesn't* do (e.g. Buffer API, module system). Obviously the later can be brought to the browser by libraries, but on the former you're out of luck.

So the question is, what node-specific stuff does that library use? If its just `require` use webpack/browserify or a babel/rollup plugin. But you're going to have to comb through that library to see what its actually using and whether or not that would be present in the browser.

Comment: Would a library like this: https://github.com/cazala/synaptic have issues other than `require`?

Comment: @VishwaIyer it says right at the beginning of the readme that its for "node and the browser" so I would guess that webpack/babel/browserify to transform the `require` calls would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both are JavaScript and have variables that have global scope, a variable from `Learner.js` can be used in `bot.js` is `Learner.js` is loaded before `bot.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Learner.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="bot.js"></script>
```

You could also use a property of `window` or (in the global scope) `this` to get the same effect.

**But**
When you are using node you'll have to make sure you are also running the node server and best way to get outputs are by sending json object by use of some `API`, and get that `json` response in `bot.js`

Comment: Except the browser would fail when I do the `require('Insert Library Here')`

Comment: Try as @Dario said.

Comment: @VishwaIyer maybe, maybe not. See my answer.